# how do I add a specific method into a current class

Tags: c#

My question is this. I have a school assignment that requires me to add a new method into a given linked link class and I'm not allowed to make any changes to my current Linked list class

iii. `RemoveParcelAtPosition(int n)`: This method will remove the node at position n in the linked list. Assume that the first node of the linked list has a position number of 1 and the second node has a position number of 2 and so on and so forth.

```
class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;  // first node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }

    public Node Head
    {
        get { return head; }
    }
    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

public void AddFront(int n)
{
        Node newNode = new Node(n);
        newNode.Link = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;

}

    public void DeleteFront()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Node temp = head;
            head = temp.Link;
            temp = null;
            count--;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Wait, what? How can you add a method to a class without changing it? Maybe you're just not allowed to change other methods?

Comment: Declare the class as `partial`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Inheritance.
Create a new Class with your required method. inherit the class in your `Linkedlist` Class.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use [extension methods](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx&ei=WIHOUeLVOIiM4AS2j4CIAQ&usg=AFQjCNHsL_hz8qi3KpRY9Jlee-voybqfrw&sig2=jBH0VwIxHbD2ZKf4-pINcg&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bGE&cad=rjt)

Something like this

```
namespace LinkedListExtension
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void RemoveParcelAtPosition(this LinkedList, int n)
        {
            // remove here
        }
    }   
}
```

and this method call will look like this:

```
_yourLinkedList.RemoveParcelAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still learning. Have no idea what extension is.

Comment: read the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)